# For ng-dynamic-forms is there any way to override an existing dynamic control without creating a new one?

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-forms

I'm using udos86/ng-dynamic-forms v14.0.1 with ui-material.

There are 3 controls that don't emit blur and focus as they're missing in the template:

- DynamicMaterialSelectComponent
- DynamicMaterialSlideToggleComponent
- DynamicMaterialSliderComponent

I have successfully created my own custom material controls in the past. Is there a way to just override the existing library control with a template that has blur & focus or do I need to create a new custom control for each of these? I know I can take the library code and modify it but I'd rather use the library as-is if possible.